# Remove duplicates in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree, duplicates

I have seen , written and tested a few logics to remove duplicates in linked list. e.g. Using two loops `(O(n2))` , or sorting and removing duplicates though it doesn't preserve order.
I am just wondering is it valid or legible if we pull out the elements of a linked list and start creating a binary search tree of them which detects duplicates using the standard duplicate detection in a binary tree algorithm.
Is that going to be any more efficient than existing logics, or worse?

Comment: that would be fast `O(n)`.. take extra memory for tree.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original order of the list ?

Comment: Reserving the original order is not a well-defined requirement. What's the original order after duplicates removal in a list `1-5-6-4-5-8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Binary Search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (BST) alternative would be faster. Lets do some analysis:

1. Instantiate a BST object `O(1)`
2. Populate the BST with each node from the linked list `N * O(log(N))`
   **Note** that duplicates would *not* be added to the tree, as part of the insert operation.
3. Rebuild the linked list from the BST `O(N)`

The BST approach to removing duplicates runs in `O(1)+O(N)+O(N*log(N)) =`***`O(N*log(N))`***

It requires *more code* and *more memory* to run, but will remove duplicates in [**quasi-linear time**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time#Linearithmic.2Fquasilinear_time).

Comment: How does building a BST of N nodes *not* equate to an O(NlogN) algorithm (nodes-inserted * search complexity) ? Its still better than O(N^2), but I don't see how you're getting O(N) for the BST-build.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are correct, I originally wrote answer hastily. I have corrected the Big O notation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `O(n)` time with `O(n)` additional memory. This is better than BST approach:

1. Allocate an array of booleans, sized n, initialize all cells to false.
2. Traverse the linked list:

   - For each node hash/map the value into a unique index in the array.
   - Set the cell value to true.
3. Create a pointer to a new list.
4. Traverse the original list:

   - For each node hash/map the value into a unique index in the array.
   - If the cell value is true, add the node to a new list.
   - Set the cell value to false.
5. Set the old list head to a new list head and delete the old one.

Comment: Hashing, as opposed to mapping, has [collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg). Two input values will produce the same output value. This algorithm using hashing is liable to remove a unique element because it shares a hash with another distinct element.

Comment: @awashburn mapping is a private case of hashing. Of course, here we are talking about collisionless hashing

Comment: @icepack, agree with creating a temporary array. You can create a parent node when iterating the old list, so you can remove the node directly in the second iteration without another list.

Answer (score 0):

The best options (fastern) is to create the binary tree to find the duplicate, but you will need more memory and code for it.

In c# you have the Dictionary, in c++ I think that there is any template of library that you can use

Answer (score 0):

Thiss solution solve the problem where no extra memory is allowed and changes the linked list in place. The solution is in C#

```
public static void removeDuplicates(Node root) { 
        Node reset = root;
        Node current = null;
        Node previous = null;
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        //initialize hash table to all 0 values
        while (root != null)
        {
            if(!h.ContainsKey(root.value))
                h.Add(root.value, 0);
            root = root.next;
        }

        root = reset;
        ///count the number of times an element appears
        while (root != null)
        {
            h[root.value] = int.Parse(h[root.value].ToString()) + 1;
            root = root.next;
        }

        root = reset;
        previous = root;
        current = previous.next;            
        while (current != null) {
            if (int.Parse(h[current.value].ToString())>1)
            {
                h[current.value] = int.Parse(h[current.value].ToString())-1;
                previous.next = current.next;
                current = current.next;
            }
            else {
                previous = previous.next;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

      // print them for visibility purposes
        while (reset != null) {
            Console.Write(reset.value + "->");
            reset = reset.next;
        }

    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node one = new Node(1);
        Node two = new Node(1);
        Node three = new Node(1);
        Node four = new Node(2);
        Node five = new Node(2);

   RemoveDuplicates(one);
   }
```